# Windows 8 freezes after every other reboot on Lenovo W520 after about 10 seconds

Tags: windows-8

I have a Lenovo W520 laptop with i7-2760QM, intel 520 SSD and Nvidia Quadro 1000m.

When i boot the PC with discrete graphics SET in BIOS, the computer totally freezes and the only thing left to do is reboot. This only happens with NVidia drivers for Windows 8 x64 installed (I've tried about 4 different drivers on Nvidia's site).

When i boot the PC with integrated graphics set in BIOS, there is a momentary "hickup" after about 10 seconds (instead of freezing) and then everything is working fine.

When i boot the PC with integrated graphics OFF and no Nvidia drivers installed, the same thing happens as described above with integrated graphics.

I've tried doing

1)

```
bcdedit /set disabledynamictick yes
```

2) Disabling VT-x in BIOS (Seriously would prefer not to disable it, since i use VM-s almost every day)

but no dice.

The only thing that worked was to enable the Hyper-v feature. I was then able to boot properly with discrete graphics and Nvidia drivers installed, but since i use VMWare for VM development this was no solution (VMWare complained about not being able to launch because of Hyper-v being installed).

I followed the instructions in [this tutorial](http://systemspecialist.net/2012/10/09/windows-8-install-hyper-v-and-vmware-workstation-9-side-by-side/), to be able to run VMWare. Then the computer just booted into a black screen past Windows logo.

**How to boot Windows 8 x64 without freezing with Quadro 1000M enabled, Nvidia Drivers installed and Hyper-v feature preferably disabled ?**

Comment: Have you updated your BIOS to the latest version and have you tried a fresh Windows 8 install (not upgrade from previous OS)?

Comment: @kobaltz Yes and yes (tried both actually, upgrade and fresh install).

Answer (score 5):

It looks like the issue that your having is not uncommon and in fact is happening to several people. The past post has a crappy work around, but does show hope and promise for an updated driver with this issue fixed down the road. Unfortunately, and this isn't a great solution, but revert back to Windows 7 until a stable solution is found.

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_cp-hardware/nvidia-quadro-1000m-causes-windows-8-to-freeze/2e1d9106-f437-4c84-bb8f-94cc5d3d4332

Answer (score 2):

Here is something wacky: try forcing the old Windows 7 drivers. This worked a computer I am working on at the moment.

Out of curiosity was this a clean install?

If you run vmware as often as you say you do, it makes 10x times more sense to just run Windows 8 in the VM and run Windows 7 for now.

Comment: He has indicated that it was both an upgrade and fresh install attempted.

Comment: I see the comment but it is not clear at what point he did the clean install. It was perhaps not clear what I asked :-)

Comment: @Misha I first upgraded from the previous installation of Windows 7. After being unable to boot i did a fresh install if that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Type in **services.msc**

Stop the **Hyper-V Virtual Machine Management** and set it to Manual

**Latest Update...**.

As per as **Nvdia & Lenovo** its a bug that is causing the issue  when **hyper -v** is enabled and they are trying to find a workaround for this
http://forum.notebookreview.com/lenovo/566338-lenovo-w520-owners-thread-743.html

Hope it helps..

Comment: No dice, unfortunately. Instead of the 10 second wait period, Windows 8 freezes right from the start of the log in screen.

Comment: I will try to find another way.....

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is still up to date but I am about to send my old W520 to my father and I installed Windows 10 on it. I ran into exactly the same freeze issues when trying to install Windows. The installation just froze at the Windows 10 logo. After some research I downloaded and burnt the Lenovo BIOS update DVD and upgraded the BIOS to 1.43 (was 1.34). After that Windows 10 installed without a hassle. However the computer just freezes 9 out of 10 times on restarting at the Windows logo. That was when I was directed to this thread in search of solutions. I disabled both Virtualization options in the BIOS->Security->Virtualization, and enabled the display option of BIOS->Config->Display->OS Detection for NVIDIA Optimus. After that W520 load Windows well without any freezes.